# Using Android Interface

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new on Android Programing. I am trying to make a count down program ,so I placed three textview to my screen. Now I want to change their position, but when i drag one of them to another location, the others gone random location. Is this a property which make easier designing, and how it uses ? 
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the textviews are displayed depends on what layout they are wrapped in.

The 2 most common layouts are LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts.

Linear Layouts arrange the linearly in either a horizontal direction, or a vertical direction.

e.g.
LinearLayout Vertical orientation
---View 1----
---View 2----
---View 3----

LinearLayout Horizontal orientation

---View 1--- ---View 2--- ---View 3---

RelativeLayouts arrange a view based on on the position of other views. For example you can say layout view 1 to the left of view 2, and above view 3. And layout view 3 at the bottom of the parent. It can get quite complicated.

I recommend you do some reading on android layouts. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html